# Simple rewrite do not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I try to make some simple redirect which looks like

```
RewriteRule ^shop.php?arttyp=Indianerflöten$ /basiskategorie/indianerfloeten-high-spirits [R=301,L]
```

but I'm missing something because does not work

Should I escape something?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:[^&]*&)*arttyp=Indianerflöten
RewriteRule ^/?shop\.php$ /basiskategorie/indianerfloeten-high-spirits [R=301,L]

# RewriteRule  ^shop.php?arttyp=Indianerflöten /basiskategorie/indianerfloeten-high-spirits [R=301,L]
# Redirect 301 /shop.php /produkte
# Redirect permanent  /shop.php?arttyp=Indianerflöten /basiskategorie/indianerfloeten-high-spirits
# RewriteRule  ^shop.php?arttyp=Indianerflöten$ /basiskategorie/indianerfloeten-high-spirits [R=301,NC,L]
# RewriteRule  ^shop.php?arttyp=Indianerflöten /basiskategorie/indianerfloeten-high-spirits [R=301,NC,L]
# RewriteRule  ^shop.php?arttyp=Instrumente\ für\ Klangtherapie$ /basiskategorie/monochorde [R=301,L]
# Redirect permanent "shop.php?arttyp=Instrumente für Klangtherapie" /basiskategorie/monochorde


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:[^&]*&)*arttyp=Indianerflöten
RewriteRule ^/?shop\.php$ /basiskategorie/indianerfloeten-high-spirits [R=301,L]
```

our attempt does not work because it will never match any incoming request. Reason is that the `RewriteRule` directive matches the path component against the provided pattern. The query string component is not part of that. You need to use a `RewriteCond` for that. You want to start reading the documentation of the tools you use. The documentation if Apache's rewriting module is of excellent quality and comes with great examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

For this to work some preconditions need to apply: the rewriting module has to be installed, loaded and enabled. If you want to use such rules in dynamic configuration files, then you also have to enable their interpretation first using the `AllowOverride` command in the http servers host configuration. But in 99% of all cases it is better to place such rules directly inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I was typing the answer.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar Yep, indeed, looks straight forward. So we kind of created an answer together :-)

Comment: thanks for feedback I just tried but still not work I will paste my whole htaccess here

Comment: @deroccha Make tripple certain you are not looking at a cached result. Clear or disable your browser cache, make a _deep reload_ or use an anonymous tab to test.

Comment: yes as suggested I'm on  anonymous tab, but still fails so I will digging myself in the docs

Comment: @deroccha Next thing to check is whether the rewriting module is enabled and applies here, as I already wrote in the answer. Have a try placing a definite syntax error in the rule set and see if that really does raise an error as it should or is silently ignored. Monitor your http servers error log file for that. Another approach to debugging such stuff is rewrite logging. It allows you to monitor exactly what is actually going on inside the rewriting engine on a step by step base.

Comment: I can produce error, that one I already tried, but deep logging I can not make because this site is on shared hosting

Comment: Well, does the rule work as expected in your local development environment? Checking that probably will save time...